# How to check if the same user in facebook app is logged in my app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am developing an app where user can be different at different times. My app allows login with facebook. Integration and all works perfectly but i got stuck at a point.
Following is the scenario:

user_a logged into my sample app with facebooksdk-> same user logged in Facebook app (In android mobile), now i show the connected status to the user in my app.
Now, I will change the user in facebook app and i will re-open my sample app. Here it is still showing the old user. In this place i have sync between facebook app user and my sample app user and if different i have to force Logout user from my app and ask him to login again. Please let me know what i am missing. Thanks

I have tried ProfileTracker as well as AccessTokenTracker but these both getting executed only if user logged out from my app .

Comment: can you show your facebook activity class

Comment: I did not implement any FacebookActivity class. I just used LoginManager to log into app in my mainActivity class

Comment: OK,
show that method, or try this:
       if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }

Comment: this will logout the existing user from my app even though user in my app and facebook app are same